# get a new table from two tables based on the columns' values in a table in SQL server:

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get a new table from two tables in SQL server:

tbl1:

```
id value
1  abc
2  abd
3  dft
```

tbl2:

```
num  abc  abd  dft   
1    5     9   0       
2    8     0   7
```

if a column is not 0 in tbl2, get id from tbl1 like:

```
 num   id
 1     1  (abc <> 0 in tbl2)    
 1     2  (abd <> 0 in tbl2)    
 2     1  (abc <> 0 in tbl2)     
 2     3  (dft <> 0 in tbl2)
```

My SQL query :

```
 select tbl2.num, case when (tbl2.abc != 0 ) then select tbl1.id from tbl1 end as id
 from tbl2, tbl1
```

But, it is not what I want. I do not want to use loop to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to join the tables, not just list them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select num, 1 as id from tbl2 where abc <> 0
union all
select num, 2 as id from tbl2 where abd <> 0
union all
select num, 3 as id from tbl2 where dft <> 0;
```

If you want to pick up the ids from the first table:

```
select t2.num, t1.id
from tbl2 cross join
     (select id from tbl1 where value = 'abc') t1
where abc <> 0
union all
select num, t1.id
from tbl2 cross join
     (select id from tbl1 where value = 'abd') t1
where abd <> 0
union all
select num, t1.id
from tbl2 cross join
     (select id from tbl1 where value = 'dft') t1
where dft <> 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpivot like this:

```
;WITH tbl1 AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
(1, 'abc'),
(2, 'abd'),
(3, 'dft')) as t1(id, value)
)
,tbl2 AS (
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
(1, 5, 9, 0),
(2, 8, 0, 7)) as t2(num, abc, abd, dft)
)

--Unpivot the table.
SELECT num, tbl1.id
FROM 
   (SELECT num, 
            CASE WHEN abc != 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END as abc,
            CASE WHEN abd != 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END as abd,
            CASE WHEN dft != 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END as dft
   FROM tbl2) p
UNPIVOT
   (value FOR id IN 
      (abc, abd, dft)
)AS unpvt
LEFT JOIN tbl1 on tbl1.value = unpvt.id
```

The result:

```
num         id
----------- -----------
1           1
1           2
2           1
2           3
```